# Why is web server needed for dimple.js examples to run?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

Some of the dimple.js examples can be run directly by saving them as a html file and opening the html file, such as this following one on the [home page](http://dimplejs.org/):

```
<head>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.6.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 800, 600);
    var data = [
      { "Word":"Hello", "Awesomeness":2000 },
      { "Word":"World", "Awesomeness":3000 }
    ];
    var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Word");
    chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Awesomeness");
    chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
    chart.draw();
  </script>
</body>
```

Other downloaded sample code, like all the examples found [here](http://dimplejs.org/examples_index.html) can only be run after you set up a local web server as described [here](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki).

I wonder why it is like this. Wouldn't this mean that when I develop a visualization using dimple.js, my audience will have to set up a local web server in order to see my visualization? Is there any way that they can just launch using web browser without additional installation?

Thanks in advance for any response!

Comment: if any of the code does (say) an ajax request, then you MUST have a webserver, because ajax is just an http call.

Comment: Those others are loading data files from the server, so it needs a web server.

Comment: Thank you for your replies @MarcB and @crashmstr! So, a follow up question is, what is the best way for people to view the dimple.js visualization I created within a company environment? Would it be to set up a company level server or they'll have to install node.js on their computers in order to see visualizations with ajax requests? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment because I dont have 50 reputation yet. I will try to answer your question you ask comment from here.

I am not sure this is the best way, but to me easiest way is to to view dimple chart is install [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) free version. It's fairly basic install, then set your document root.

[image]